# PHP: get a result from a chaining method from extended classes?

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining, php-5.4

I am trying to get a result from a chaining method from extended classes below,

```
class Base
{
    protected $id;

    public function setId($input) {

        $this->id = $input;

        return $this;
    }
}

class PageChildren extends Base
{
    public function getID()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}


class Page extends Base
{
    public $hasChidren;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->hasChidren = new PageChildren();
    }
}

$page = new Page();
var_dump($page->setId(10)->hasChidren->getID());
```

But I get `null` instead of `10`. What shall I do to get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$page->hasChidren->setId(10);
var_dump(page->hasChidren->getID();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the ID of hasChidren, which is a new object of type PageChildren whose ID has never been set, you are not accessing the original object of type base to which you set the ID

You create a page object, when you create it one of his attributes contains a PageChildren object. Then you set the ID of your page object. And in the end you are getting the ID from the PageChildren object, not the Page object.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NULL` since, when you do a

```
$page = new Page();
```

your constructor will run first which has the `getID()` method. The `getID()` method does not have anything to return and thus you get a `NULL`